# TCP| C#| Accepting Multiple Clients and Manage Them on the Same Port

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, listener, port

I'm trying to accept and manage multiple clients on the same port using TCP.
I tried to use some answers I found on Google, but non of them worked.
The main idea is dedicated form applications (used for clients) connects to a console application (which used as a listener). this is what I have till now:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int counter = 0;

            // set the TcpListener on port 13000 
            int port = 13000;
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

            // Start listening for client requests
            server.Start();


            // Buffer for reading data
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            string data;

            //Enter the listening loop 
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests. 
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                counter += 1;

                //Control each client
                var t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(AccentClient));
                t.Start();

                //Handle the client that just connected
                handleClinet handle_client = new handleClinet();
                handle_client.startClient(client, counter.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                while (i != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Received: {0}", data));
                    Console.WriteLine("Fixed: {0}", data.Replace("$", ""));

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.Replace("$", "") + " Bla";

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Sent: {0}", data));
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                //client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void AccentClient(object clientObj)
    {
        var client = clientObj as TcpClient;

    }
}

//Class to handle each client request separatly
public class handleClinet
{
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo)
    {
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }
    private void doChat()
    {
        int requestCount = 0;
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[100000];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "From client- " + clNo + dataFromClient);

                rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);
                serverResponse = "Server to clinet(" + clNo + ") " + rCount;
                sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: so whats your problem ?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: it's just doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your `AcceptClient` method doesn't do absolutely anything as it stands:

```
public static void AccentClient(object clientObj)
{
    var client = clientObj as TcpClient;
}
```

So the whole thread you're spawning when a client connects does nothing.

Second, given your current code, when a client connects, your main thread will stop listening for other clients and start communicating with the one that just connected:

```
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

            // ...

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            while (i != 0)
            {
                // ...
                i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
```

So no other clients are accepted until the current one is finished.

Third, not only you're accepting and communicating with the client on the main thread, but you're also communciating with the client on yet another thread, at the same time:

```
            handleClinet handle_client = new handleClinet();
            handle_client.startClient(client, counter.ToString());
```

And these are defined as:

```
public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo)
{
    // ...
    Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
    ctThread.Start();
}
private void doChat()
{
    // ...
    while ((true))
    {
            // ...
            requestCount = requestCount + 1;
            NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
            Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "From client- " + clNo + dataFromClient);
            // ...
    }
}
```

This will always fail to work predictably.

---

To summarize:

1. Remove the no-op.
2. Change the code so that your main thread only calls the asynchronous client handler.
3. After calling the asynchronous handler, make sure the loop in the main thread doesn't do anything else but immediately goes back to accept the next client.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your fast reply! Second, if you had to choose, what would you use? the AccentClien function (of course, after adding things that the function does) or the handleClinet class?

Comment: The `handleClient` class is asynchronous (it creates another thread and communicates with the client on that thread), so I would choose that. Otherwise the next client will have to wait for the previous client to finish.

Comment: actually, right after I wrote the comment, I tried few things and the async worked the best. Thank you!